# the first time an element in a vector is larger than another vector in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

I have 2 vectors (x and y) of the same length in dolphindb. How can I get the first (or the 100th) time an element in x is larger than the corresponding element in y? I can write a loop but since dolphindb is a vector based language I feel it's probably not the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try function `at` to specify a Boolean expression and locate the element in a vector. The syntax is `at(X, [index])`. Modify the index to change the condition.

For example:

```
a=1..1000
b=1000..1
at(a>b)[0]
//return the index 500

a[at(a>b)[99]]
//return the value 600
```